# Ubuntu Shutdown Timeout too short

Tags: virtualbox, suspend, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2. I have Virtual Box 4.3.26 installed running a headless CentOS VM. I use the `vboxautostart-service` to start and save the virtual box at startup and shutdown as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204863).

In general this works well, however suspending the virtual machine during shutdown takes some time. Unfortunately, the Ubuntu shutdown process does not wait long enough, so that the virtual machine is killed before it is completely saved.

How can I increase the timeout, so that the virtual machine has a chance to suspend?

Comment: Just make the service return only after the VM is down (remove & or add sleep loop) show us cat /etc/init.d/vbox* for a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added simple sleep command to the stop section of the init script as suggested by @user1133275. This works well. Of course this could be optimized, but it is good enough for the time being.

`stop() {
    [ -z "$VBOXAUTOSTART_DB" ] && exit 0
    [ -z "$VBOXAUTOSTART_CONFIG" ] && exit 0

```
PARAMS="--stop --config $VBOXAUTOSTART_CONFIG"
# prevent inheriting this setting to VBoxSVC
unset VBOX_RELEASE_LOG_DEST

for user in `ls $VBOXAUTOSTART_DB/*.stop`
do
    start_daemon `basename $user | sed -ne "s/\(.*\).stop/\1/p"` $binary $PARAMS
done
sleep 40
return $RETVAL
```

}
`